# Gulp - wiredep not injecting - no error - but gulp-inject is working

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower, wiredep

This is my wiredep task in **gruntfile.js**

```
gulp.task('wiredep',function(){
var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var options = config.getWiredepOptions();
return gulp
    .src(config.index)
    .pipe(wiredep(options))
    .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(config.js)))
    .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(config.css)))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.client));
});
```

This is my **gulp.config.js** file having config data

```
module.exports = function(){
var client = './src/client/';
var clientApp = client + 'app/';
var temp = './.tmp/';
var config = {
    client:client,
    temp: temp,
    //index file location
    index: client + 'index.html',
    //wiredepJsFiles
    js:[
        clientApp + '**/*.module.js',
        clientApp + '**/*.js',
        '!' + clientApp + '**/*.spec.js'
    ],
    css:temp + '**/*.css',
    // bower config here for wiredep
    bower:{
        json:'./bower.json',
        directory:'./bower_components',
        ignorePath:'../..'
    }
};
config.getWiredepOptions = function(){
    return {
        bowerJson:config.bower.json,
        directory:config.bower.directory,
        ignorePath:config.bower.ignorePath,
    };
};
return config;
};
```

I placed **bower:css** and **bower:js** tags in index.html along with inject:js and inject:css

**EDIT:** The tags injected in index.html are

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->

<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endbower -->
```

I can successfully inject with gulp-inject but wiredep fails to inject.I have no errors generated from wiredep.

P.S I've added **overrides** property to **bower.json** for packages like bootstrap and font awesome.The problem is that none of the bower packages are getting injected.

Comment: Can you update the question with the `index.html` injection tags? We trust that you have them, but having them wrong could be a problem.

Comment: By the way, I use wiredep and inject and we have almost identical config files. Your wiredep task looks good, but my preference is to have wiredep and inject in separate tasks.

Comment: FYI, if you are not already using [useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) I highly recommend it. It collapses all your references into a single file. I use it for release

Comment: @WilmerSaint useref sounds amazing. I'm just getting started with gulp  and since wiredep is so cool I tried it and it's not working. I'm looking forward to use useref too :)